# How to debug in release mode

Tags: xamarin

Is there a way to debug a app in release mode in Xamarin? When i start debugging in release mode it just runs the app without starting the debugger.I am asking this question, because app works in debugger mode, but crashes on release mode.

Comment: Are using Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes I am using Visual Studio

Comment: Release mode put break mode you can debug

Comment: I did, but it did not work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's not really a good reason to **debug** in a `Release` configuration per-say. The reason why there are separate configurations is exactly for this reason(One to Debug, One to Release). If anything, you can `Enable developer instrumentation (debugging and profiling)` on a Release configuration if you really wanted to do that.

Android:
[image]

iOS:
[image]

Otherwise you can do the opposite from within a `Debug` configuration in the sense that you can change the `Linker` and other Configuration settings to mimic the `Release` configuration. You can view what those might be within your project's `.csproj`.

Typically it's best to just debug crashes on `Release` configurations by playing around with the `Linker` settings as it's the most common reason something is failing. That with a combination of the platform's specific logs will help you identify exactly what's going on.

Android:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/

iOS:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/

Comment: Please open up a new question describing your issues.

Comment: this is unfortunately not working in VS4Mac in latest version. Debugger will not be attached