# "arg_targetinvocationexception" - how determine the cause?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO4f4.jpg)

```
private HttpClient CreateHttpClient(string UserToken = "")
            {
                HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));         
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(AppConfig.HeaderKey_AppToken, AppConfig.HeaderValue_AppToken);
              
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserToken))
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("UserToken", UserToken);
                }
                return httpClient;
            }
```

The Exception is occure on "HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);" this line

I have attached image what exact "arg_targetinvocationexception" issue i am facing please check.I am using MAUI And latest preview versio on VS2022 .When i am access this function that time I'm facing "arg_targetinvocationexception" this issue

Main thing when I'm run the application in debugg mode that time It's working fine.But when I'm run the application on Realese mode that time show this error indide a alert box show in attached image.

```
private async Task SendOTPClicked()
        {
            try
            {
                var networkFlag = Common.Instance.IsNetworkConnected();
                if (networkFlag)
                {
                    CustomProgressDialog.Instance.ShowLoading(AppResources.Sending_lbl);
                    string url = $"{AppConfig.ApiBaseUrl}{AppConfig.ApiKeypoints_sendotp}";
                    string phonenumber = CountryCode.Replace("+", "") + PhoneNumber;
                    string ApiUrl = $"{url}{phonenumber}";
                    var response = await RequestProviderService.Instance.PostAsync<ResponseViewModel<string>>(ApiUrl, phonenumber, "", AppConfig.TenantId_Value, "", null);
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        if (response.Status)
                        {
                         
                               await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync(response.Message, AppResources.Title_Success, AppResources.Ok_Flag);
                         
                            
                            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new EnterOTPView(CountryCode.Replace("+", "") + _phonenumber, User));
                            CustomProgressDialog.Instance.HideLoading();                
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string errorMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.ErrorMessage) ? response.Message : response.ErrorMessage;
                            CustomProgressDialog.Instance.HideLoading();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
                            {
                                  await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync(errorMessage, AppResources.Alert_Label, AppResources.Ok_Flag);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CustomProgressDialog.Instance.HideLoading();                        
                    }                        
                }
                else
                {
                  
                        await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync(AppResources.NetworkError_CheckConnection, AppResources.Alert_Label, AppResources.Ok_Flag);
                 
                    
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                CustomProgressDialog.Instance.HideLoading();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Which **specific** line causes the exception?  What does the stack trace show?  What does the InnerException property show?

Comment: when i am access this SendOTPClicked() function that time "arg_targetinvocationexception" msg show on my alert box ,I have not found in any specific line .Or Main thing when I'm run the application in debugg mode that time It's working .But when I'm run the application on Realese mode that time show this error

Comment: @Jason Do you have any idea how can i resolve this.

Comment: add some logging to capture the details of the exception while in Release mode

Comment: If I understand correctly, the alert dialog is from your code. It is information returned from `RequestProviderService…` call. You’ll need to add code inside whatever that calls, to return more information about what went wrong.

Comment: Is there another way to reslve .

Comment: Actually, there might be - given that it works on Debug build. Compare the build settings between build and release configurations. Take screenshots of both, so you know what the defaults are, and what is different between them. And make sure your `.csproj` files are backed up (usually by saving all your source in a git repository), so you can go back to what they were. Change your debug build **link** settings to match the release build. Does that break it? Usually that will do it - and maybe debug build can give you more information. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38663884/199364.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i have check ,but still issue is there

Comment: Try to integrate [App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin) in your project to figure out what is going wrong in release mode .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT Nothing happned.I have try this also.issue is still there

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT @
ToolmakerSteve
 I have edit the question ,Where exact the problem is occure .Please check

Comment: Try to set handler as parameter in `HttpClient` initialization , check https://stackoverflow.com/a/70169928/8187800 .

Comment: I have used "AndroidMessageHandler"and resove my issue 
if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                {
                    //HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                    var Msghandler = new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler();
                    httpClient = new HttpClient(Msghandler); 
                }
                else
                {
                    httpClient = new HttpClient();
                }

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT ,@ToolmakerSteve   

Thank You for your responce

Comment: Would you mind sharing your solution below as answer and mark it ? It is helpful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use "AndroidMessageHandler()" and resolve my issue

```
 if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                    {
                        //HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                        var Msghandler = new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler();
                        httpClient = new HttpClient(Msghandler); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    }
```